How to Track New Token Listings and Prices on the Solana Blockchain Programmatically?
I'm building a simple application to track new token listings on the Solana blockchain, along with their current prices. I want to retrieve information such as the token name, token address, and current price.
I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically, similar to how DEXTools provides token information for Ethereumor Solana.
Could someone guide me on the best approach or libraries I should use to accomplish this on Solana?
Any examples or resources would be highly appreciated!

Depending on the kind of tokens, you can use different methods.
This is working for new raydium pools:
https://github.com/archiesnipes/solana-new-token-monitor/blob/main/monitorNewTokens.ts
This is working for new pump.fun tokens:
https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk
And then you get metadata from Helius for price info, or use dexscreener or birdeye APIs.
If the speed of your application is mostly determined by api and rpc calls, you can use Typescript, it's fast enough for most use cases. web3js packages are the most used libraries in the ecosystem i guess.

thanks but both lins are the same !

Sorry, fixed it.

Using the Jupiter API is also a good approach.
https://station.jup.ag/docs/
async function getTokens() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://tokens.jup.ag/tokens?tags=verified');
        const tokenList = console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching tokens:', error);
    }
}

async function getSymbolPrice(symbol: string) {
    const url = `https://price.jup.ag/v6/price?ids=${symbol}`;
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const data = response.data;
        console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching symbol price:', error);
    }
}


Heya and thanks for the answer! Someone flagged this as a link-only answer - can you please add a code example using the relevant API?
